# Definition of homogeneus manifold as a quotient

Tags: general-topology, matrices, differential-geometry, lie-algebras, quotient-spaces

Consider the group 
$$\mathfrak{G}=\{g\in M(5,\mathbb{R})\;|\;g^{t}Bg=B,\;\det g=1,\;g_{11}>0\},$$
where $B$ is the matrix
$$B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{array}\right).$$

Now take the subgroup 
$$\mathfrak{K}=\{u\in\mathfrak{G}\;|\;\sigma u\sigma^{-1}=u\},$$
where $\sigma$ is
$$\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
 \end{array}\right).\\$$

In the paper that I am reading the author states that $\mathfrak{G}/\mathfrak{K}$ is a homogeneous manifold.

To define a topological quotient space one needs an equivalence relation over the original space. In our case, $\sigma$ is not even an element of $\mathfrak{G}$ so I can't find the way to define such a relation on this space using the definition of $\mathfrak{K}$.

Surely I'm missing something here... Could anyone explain why this quotient space is well-defined? In the paper the author uses theory of Lie groups and Lie algebras, which I'm just starting to learn about, and the gap might come from there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The space you are looking at is the space of cosets of a closed subgroup in a Lie group.

Comment: Okay. And since the subgroup is not normal, the space is not a group but just manifold on which the group acts, right? And this is the homogeneous space.

Comment: That's basically right. If the subgroup were normal, it would also be a homgeneous space, but a group in addition.